# Replacing text in a .bat file with a random line in a .txt file

Tags: batch-file

I'm messing around with command line programs, and im having the programs export to a "output.txt". I would like a batch file to pick a random line from "output.txt" and replace a portion of text in a batch file. If possible, It would be awesome if it could save it as another .batch file.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `find` command to count the number of lines in the file, pick a random line number (now that I know how many there are), and then use the `more` command to jump to a specific line of the file.  Here's an example of how to implement this:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=3" %%a in (`find /v /c "" output.txt`) do set /a numLines = %%a
set /a line = %random% %% %numLines%
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('more +%line% output.txt') do echo %%a > another.bat & exit
```

- `find /v /c "" output.txt` Here I find all lines NOT matching an empty string using the `/v` switch, which results in all lines because the string is empty (special case), and then I output the number of matching lines using the `/c` switch.
- `set /a numLines = %%a` I set the variable `numLines` to the output of the above command, which was stored in `%%a`.
- `set /a line = %random% %% %numLines%` I set line to a random number up to the value of `numLines` using the modulo operator.
- `more +%line% output.txt` I skip to the line number I just generated with the above command
- `echo %%a > another.bat` I echo the line to a file called "another.bat" (this could be whatever file you want)
- `& exit` This breaks the `for` loop, so it doesn't print all of the remaining lines.  If you don't want to exit the program yet, you could make this a `goto` statement instead.

Comment: So I was having the same problem with my initial go at it: So the test .txt file im using has a bunch of lines filed with garbage to test it out " dasijfijfs    fsoufhoudfh   wsafoih  gf" and whenever I run your/my initial command, it always outputs the final line, gf , to the output destination. It never outputs any other line

Comment: @Tacodude the problem is, the `for` loop loops over each line (beginning with line `!line!` to the last line). The `&exit` is essential to break the loop after the first iteration. You probably want `goto :continue` and a label `:continue` in the very next line.

Comment: @Charlie: you can turn your good answer into a very good one when you implement my suggestion. (and `find /v /c ""` is enough to capture each line, even empty ones - counterintuitive but true)

Comment: @Tacodude stephan is correct, the `& exit` or a `goto` statement is necessary, otherwise the program just keeps overwriting the file with each line until it reaches the end, so all you are left with is the last line.  Try copying my code verbatim into a new batch file, and it should work.

Comment: @Stephan Thank you for the suggestion for the `find` command.  I had forgotten that little trick!  I knew there was a better way to do it.  I'll update my answer.  And regarding using a `goto` statement, I already have a sentence explaining that in my answer, which I think should be sufficient.

Comment: another little trick: `type output.txt | find /c /v ""` or `find /c /v "" < output.txt` returns just the number, so you don't need any `tokens`: `for /f %%a in ('find /v /c "" ^< output.txt') do set "numLines=%%a"`

Comment: or `... do set /a line=%random% %% %%a`